# Reference to com dll in c# What if COM is unregistered

Tags: c#, com

I want to use third-party COM dll in my c# project. I've added "Reference" in Visual studio and got access to the COM types. All works fine.

Question: What if target machine where end-user will work has no that COM dll installed?
My app will not run at all or I can handle this situation safely somehow?

Comment: On a side note, if you're looking to use xcopy-style deployment without registering the COM DLL, that still [may be possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508515/1768303).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same way as when you run your program with a missing .NET assembly, you'll get an exception when you try to create an instance of the object.  The underlying COMException is for error code 0x80040154, "Class not registered".

This is easily tested btw, just unregister the COM server with Regsvr32.exe, /u option.  Writing excessive amounts of code to deal with a missing DLL isn't typically that useful, given how easy it is to fix the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The binaries to your program should contain all the necessary libraries that you are using. It's all in the bin folder. If you give the computer everything that's in there your program will work fine.

Comment: Not COM references - they are not loaded from the 'bin' folder but are referenced by the COM IDs stored in the registry.

Comment: Oh okay. Didn't realize there was a difference.